# Nested parameterized types with Dart 1.22.0 new instantiate to bound rules

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I have an issue related to the new instantiate to bound rule in Dart 1.22.0. I have a `BaseModel` class that takes a parameterized type called `ParentType` that itself extends `BaseModel`.

Not all BaseModels have a specific ParentType, and if I instantiate BaseModel as the ParentType, then I get infinite rule breaking.

Here's an example:

```
abstract class BaseModel<ParentType extends BaseModel> {
    ParentType parentModel
}

class ParentModel extends BaseModel<BaseModel<...>> {}

class ChildModel extends BaseModel<ParentModel> {}
```

I’m going to be ignoring the rule for now as this issue hasn't seemed to have any impact on development.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on what you want to accomplish, but assuming that you want `ParentModel` to be usable as any kind of `BaseModel` (where the `parentModel` field will always be `null`), then this may be what you want:

```
abstract class BaseModel<ParentType extends BaseModel<ParentType>> {
  ParentType parentModel;
}

class ParentModel extends BaseModel<Null> {}

class ChildModel extends BaseModel<ParentModel> {}
```

If not, I would need to know more about what the constraints and goals of your problem are.

Comment: This satisfies the analyzer for the basic example, but it breaks where I have more complex inheritance.
`class ParentModel<ParentType> extends ChildModel<ParentType>`

`class ChildModel extends BaseModel<ParentType extends BaseModel>`
My codebase is too large and complex to make all of these typing changes, and I don't see the benefit. I am resigned to ignoring the rule. I've struggled with strong mode in the past, which was the impetus to implement this pattern to begin with.  Before this, I was overriding field types, which to me seems like a preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
abstract class BaseModel<ParentType extends BaseModel<Null>>
```

Comment: That seems to work for the very simple example, but it is not working for my more complex BaseModel relationships.

Comment: Can you update your question with a concrete example?